# Accessing an element in an arraylist (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I've been trying to get the salary on the code I've been working on so I can compute the salary after `tax = tsalary`. Unfortunately, I've hit a bump ever since I was trying to access the salary from my `ArrayList`.
I tried getting the salary via `salary = li.next().getSalary();` but when I run it, I get an output not on that certain employee number I'm trying to compute.

Even hints of it will be plenty helpful. Thank you

```
case 5:
            found = false;
            double tsalary = 1;
            System.out.print("Enter Employee Number: ");
            empNo = sc.nextInt();
            li = al.listIterator();
            while (li.hasNext()){
                EmployeeRecords e = li.next();
                salary = li.next().getSalary();
                if (e.getEmployeeNum() == empNo) {
                    if (salary >= 20001) {
                        tsalary = salary * 0.75;
                    } else {
                        tsalary = salary * 0.80;
                    }
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if(!found){
                System.out.println("Record not available / found.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(empNo + "  " + name +  "'s salary after tax is " + tsalary + ".");
            }
```

Comment: Why not `e.getSalary()`? I don't think you want to call `li.next()` twice.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @JustAnotherDeveloper in comments,the problem lies here.

```java
EmployeeRecords e = li.next();
salary = li.next().getSalary();
```

`Iterator.next()` always returns the next element in the iteration and moves the pointer to it.

You have already fetched the object using `li.next()`, now if you call `li.next()` again it will return and move to the next object from the list. Thus you will never get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of next() twice seems to be the problem.
You can try,

```
EmployeeRecords e = li.next();
salary = e.getSalary();
```

Or not using iterator and by using for each loop (if "al" can be iterated using for each)

```
for(EmployeeRecords e : al) {
    salary = e.getSalary();
    long currentEmpNo = e.getEmployeeNum();
    if (currentEmpNo == empNo) {
        // and the rest of the code
    }
}
```